# GitLab CI predefined environment variables not recognised in only clauses?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to use [GitLab CI predefined variables (Environment variables)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#predefined-variables-environment-variables) in the `only` clause of a job in **.gitlab-ci.yml**.

I have a project hosted at http://gitlab.myorg.com/jamiet/test-ci-variables (GitLab version is "9.5.2-ee"). Here is the contents of **.gitlab-ci.yml**:

```
stages:
    - mystage

.templ: &templ
    stage: mystage
    image: docker-dev/centos-base/7.3.1611/
    tags:
        - kubernetes
    script:
        - echo "hello world"

use absolute values:
    <<: *templ
    only:
        - master@jamiet/test-ci-variables

use $CI_PROJECT_NAME:
    <<: *templ
    only:
        - master@jamiet/$CI_PROJECT_NAME

use ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}:
    <<: *templ
    only:
        - master@jamiet/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
```

When the CI pipeline runs it only runs job `use absolute values`:

[image]

which suggests to me that either it isn't recognising `$CI_PROJECT_NAME` or I've got the syntax wrong. Anyone know?

Comment: I don't think you can use variables in the `only` section for your branches. Have you tried hardcoding the branches?

Comment: yep, hardcoding works fine. See above in job `use absolute values`. I eventually came to the same conclusion as you, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Was also puzzled by this.
The solution is:
Variable check **won't work** in case:

```
only:
  variables:
    - $VARIABLE == master@jamiet/{}
    - master@jamiet/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
    - master@jamiet/$CI_PROJECT_NAME
```

But **works** with a bare variable:

```
only:
  variables:
    - $VARIABLE == $CI_PROJECT_NAME
    - ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
    - $CI_PROJECT_NAME
```

Try redefining your variable in your template and use it like so.